# Is it possible to recover the OpenID used to log in on english.SE?

Tags: support, login

My fiancé doesn't remember the OpenID she used to log in on english.SE, and she didn't enable the browser she used to remember the login data.
Is it possible for her to get the OpenID she used to log in on english.SE?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If she can find the specific account, then it may be possible to do so *if* she edited her profile to include her email. In all likelihood, she will have to contact team@stackexchange.com to resolve this.